# What is the correct way to call a function with param on click only?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call function on click, by passing `params`, but not happening. as soon as page loads all my functions are called.

what is the correct way to handle the `onClick` with params?

here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { inject, observer } from "mobx-react";

@inject("store")
@observer
class ToDoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.store = props.store;
    this.todoName = React.createRef();
  }

  formHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.store.listUpdater(this.todoName.current.value);
    e.target.reset();
  };

  showItem = item => {
    console.log(item);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.store.Store.todo.map(item => (
            <li onClick={this.showItem(item)}>{item}</li> 
            //calls on page loads.. looking to call only on click!!
          ))}
        </ul>
        <form onSubmit={this.formHandler}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="text" ref={this.todoName} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ToDoList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways, really.

**Fast and easy, but less recommended:**

This solution is the fastest, in terms of programming, because they are both one-liners. Their drawback is that anytime your component re-renders, you will be generating a new function (that's what `() => ...` does). This isn't a big deal normally, other than it may, in larger collections, introduce some extra delay to your rendering. Usually though, this is negligible.

```
<li onClick={() => this.showItem(item)}>{item}</li>
```

or

```
<li onClick={this.showItem.bind(this, item)}>{item}</li>
```

---

**More verbose, but recommended:**

The recommended way to do this, is to define the funciton, along with its parameter, only once. Here, our `onClick` doesn't get a new function on each re-render. Instead, it has a static reference to `this.click` which calls the callback we passed as a prop from the parent, along with the argument.

```
<MyListItem onClick={this.showItem} item={item} />
```

Where `MyListItem` a custom component you would write. Something like:

```
class MyListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }

  click() {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.item);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li onClick={this.click}>{this.props.item}</li>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
      {this.store.Store.todo.map(item => (
        <li onClick={this.showItem.bind(this, item)}>{item}</li> 
        //calls on page loads.. looking to call only on click!!
      ))}
    </ul>
```

or

```
 <ul>
      {this.store.Store.todo.map(item => (
        <li onClick={() => this.showItem(item)}>{item}</li> 
        //calls on page loads.. looking to call only on click!!
      ))}
    </ul>
```

Comment: How your solution differs from the other (more verbose) answer?